# Pointer to char vs String

Tags: c++, c

Consider these two pieces of code. They're converting base10 number to baseN number, where `N` is the number of characters in given alphabet. Actually, they generate permutations of letters of given alphabet. It's assumed that 1 is equal to first letter of the alphabet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned long long ull;
using namespace std;

void conv(ull num, const string alpha, string *word){
    int base=alpha.size();
    *word="";
    while (num) {
        *word+=alpha[(num-1)%base];
        num=(num-1)/base;
    }
}

int main(){
    ull nu;
    const string alpha="abcdef";
    string word;
    for (nu=1;nu<=10;++nu) {
        conv(nu,alpha,&word);
        cout << word << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long long ull;

void conv(ull num, const char* alpha, char *word){
    int base=strlen(alpha);
    while (num) {
        (*word++)=alpha[(num-1)%base];
        num=(num-1)/base;
    }
}

int main() {
    char *a=calloc(10,sizeof(char)); 
    const char *alpha="abcdef";
    ull h;
    for (h=1;h<=10;++h) {
        conv(h,alpha,a);
        printf("%s\n", a);
    }
}
```

Output is the same:

> a
>
> b
>
> c
>
> d
>
> aa
>
> ba
>
> ca
>
> da

*No, I didn't forget to reverse the strings, reversal was removed for code clarification.*

For some reason speed is very important for me. I've tested the speed of executables compiled from the examples above and noticed that the one written n C++ using `string` is more than *10 times* less fast than the one written in C using `char *`.

Each executable was compiled with `-O2` flag of GCC. I was running tests using much bigger numbers to convert, such as 1e8 and more.

The question is: why is `string` less fast than `char *` in that case?

Comment: That C-style string handling you do will not work as you expect, as you change the pointer `a`.

Comment: To do that with pointers, you have to know the exact length of the char array. If you use a string, the string dynamically allocates memory on every additon. Which is why it is way slower

Comment: ` 'Pointer addition' means I try to modify text using pointers`..well, ___not always___.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, yes, I do, I'm trying to _add more text_ to given string.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, but that's what I mean :)

Comment: @ForceBru You're also dropping the original value of `a`, meaning you can never `free()` it, which is certainly part of "will not work" in my world.

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, what i'm trying to say is that _may_ not be the only usage always. :-)

Comment: The simple fact that your "pointer addition" implementation is **very broken** is proof enough that you should prefer `std::string` over the "pointers" solution.

Comment: @NikBougalis: it's not broken (wtf?). but you have to be careful and know what you're doing...

Comment: If you already know the maximum length of the buffer you need, you can use `string::reserve()` and the performance may improve.

Comment: `*a='n';
++a;
*a='o';` does not "append characters".

Comment: @dmg, why It doesn't??

Comment: If you *don't* already know the make string length, use `stringstream` in C++.

Comment: In your "pointer" version you make a buffer of 5 chars. Fill it with zeroes and add two characters at the start (also you are "loosing" the pointer). In your "std::string", you make an empty string and append to it two chars (probably causing at least one allocation). If you want you can use `string.reserve` to request some fixed capacity.

Comment: "runs faster than.."  - *prove it*. Many `std::string` release-optimized implementations include short-string no-alloc solutions.  I would expect a string of three chars fits that bill, so as-posted I find it hard to believe a malloc, a memset, and a couple pointer-writes+incs are faster than a couple of stack-var writes. I'd like to see how you measured this.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It's **very** broken. (1) There's no null terminator, so it's not *really* a string in the "null-terminated sequence of bytes" sense. (2) Where does `a` point to after the second line of his sample? It effectively loses all appended content. (3) How do you know the original value of `a` to release the allocated memory? I could go on but the simple fact is that the two bits of code aren't even equivalent.

Comment: @NikBougalis, it **does** have null-terminator. See `memset()` call.

Comment: @ForceBru: I missed that - I stand corrected but the other criticisms remain valid. Your implementation is broken.

Comment: @ForceBru Your new code snippets still aren't equivalent: You're passing the `string` by value to the `add` function, meaning that it will be copied. The `+=` inside the function is applied only to the _copy_ of `a`, so `a` will in fact not change when you call `add(a)`.

Comment: @ForceBru Now the loop is essentially assigning the same value (`a + some_other_character`) to `c` 3 times in the loop. The snippets are still not equivalent because you're passing the `char` array by pointer and the `string` by value which are different things. I'd suggest you read up on references and how to pass by reference, they're important concepts in C++.

Comment: Rewritten the question completely so it's more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Your code snippets are *not* equivalent. `*a='n'` does *not* append to the `char` array. It changes the first `char` in the array to `'n'`.

---

In C++, `std::string`s should be preferred to `char` arrays, because they're a lot easier to use, for example appending is done simply with the `+=` operator.

Also they automatically manage their memory for you which `char` arrays don't do. That being said, `std::string`s are much less error prone than the manually managed `char` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> It's possible to use both char * and string to handle some text in C++. It seems to me that string addition is much slower than pointer addition. Why does this happen?

That is because when you use a char array or deal with a pointer to it (char*) the memory is only allocated once. What you describe with "addition" is only an iteration of the pointer to the array. So its just moving of a pointer.

```
// Both allocate memory one time:
char test[4];
char* ptrTest = new char[4];
// This will just set the values which already exist in the array and will
// not append anything.
*(ptrTest++) = 't'
*(ptrTest++) = 'e';
*(ptrTest++) = 's';
*(ptrTest) = 't';
```

When you use a string instead, the `+=` operator actually *appends* characters to the end of your string. In order to accomplish this, memory will be *dynamically* allocated every time you append something to the string. This process does take longer than just iterating a pointer.

```
// This will allocate space for one character on every call of the += operator
std::string test;
test += 't';
test += 'e';
test += 's';
test += 't';
```

Comment: `*a='0'` is not appending to the `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a trace of your code you get:

```
*a='n';
// 'n0000'
//  ^
//  a
++a;
// 'n0000'
//   ^
//   a
*a='o'
// 'no000'
//   ^
//   a
```

In the end, a points to its original address + 1, wich is o. If you print a you will get 'o'.

Anyways, what if you need 'nothing' instead of 'no'? It wont fit in 5 chars and you will need to reallocate mem etc. That kind of things is what string class do for you behind the scenes, and faster enough so it's not a problem almost every scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string a(2,' ');
a[0] = 'n';
a[1] = 'o';
```

Change the size of your string in the constructor or use the reserve, resize methods, that is your choice.

You are mixing different things in your question, one is a raw representation of bytes that can get interpreted as a string, no semantics or checks, the other is an abstraction of a string with checks, believe me, it is a lot of more important the security and avoid segfaults that can lead on code injection and privilege escalation than 2ms.

Answer (score 0):

From the std::string documentation ([here](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html)) you can see, that the

`basic_string& operator+=(charT c)`

is equivalent to calling `push_back(c)` on that string, so

```
string a;
a+='n';
a+='o';
```

is equivalent to:

```
string a;
a.push_back('n');
a.push_back('o');
```

The `push_back` does take care of a lot more than the raw pointer operations and is thus slower. It for instance takes care of automatic memory management of the string class.